# Brightness keys not recognized

Tags: arch-linux, brightness

I use use an HP Elitebook 840 G6 with Arch linux, and it seems that the brightness keys are not recognized.

I can change the brightness by writing to `/sys/class/backlight/...`, so the problem really is with the key detection.

When I press the brightness keys, nothing happens neither in `xev` nor in `dmesg`. Any idea about how to "debug" this? Is there another program to detect registered keypresses? (I know about `setkeycodes`, but this doesn't help because I have no way of knowing the codes of the brightness keys -- if they are detected at all.)

Comment: You could try `showkey` in console, but if the others report nothing... Well, worth giving a try.

Comment: Oh actually that reports something! Only issue is that brightness up, brightness down, and mute have the same keycode. Many thanks!

Comment: I should add that this happens only when running `shewkey -k`. `showkey -s`, for scancodes, does not print anything when I press the backlight keys.

Comment: Hi @Quasímodo It's super strange, but since this morning the brightness keys work! I have no idea why that is.